# Getting errors not quite sure why this is my first cobol program

Tags: cobol, gnucobol

Im slowly learning COBOL and am doing some challenges to get better but i am having a weird problem that i cant seem to trace and i wanted to see if anyone else can help

I double and triple checked that what was supposed to be in area A and B where in their proper col numbers

```
IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
    PROGRAM-ID. CIRCLES.

    ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
    CONFIGURATION SECTION.
    SOURCE-COMPUTER.
    OBJECT-COMPUTER.

    INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION.
    FILE-CONTROL.


    DATA DIVISION.
    FILE SECTION.

    WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
    01  WS-CONSTANTS.
        05  WS-PI              PIC 9V99999 VALUE 3.14159.
    01   WS-CIRCLE.
        05 WS-AREA              PIC 999V99 VALUE ZEROES.
        05 WS-RADIUS            PIC 9999V99 VALUE ZEROES.
        05 WS-CIRCUMFERENCE     PIC 99999V99 VALUE ZEROES.
    01   WS-DISPLAY-VALUES.
        05 WS-DISPLAY-AREA                     PIC ZZ99.99.
        05 WS-DISPLAY-CIRCUMFERENCE  PIC ZZ99.99.



    PROCEDURE DIVISION.

    0100-PROCESS-RECORDS.

        DISPLAY "Please enter radius of circle: ".
        ACCEPT WS-RADIUS.
        COMPUTE WS-CIRCUMFRENCE = 2 * WS-PI * WS-RADIUS.
        MOVE WS-CIRCUMFRENCE TO WS-DISPLAY-CIRCUMFRENCE.
        DISPLAY "Circle Circumfrence is: ", WS-DISPLAY-CIRCUMFRENCE.
        COMPUTE WS-RADIUS = WS-PI * WS-RADIUS * WS-RADIUS.
        MOVE WS-AREA TO WS-DISPLAY-AREA.
        DISPLAY "Circle area is:  ", WS-DISPLAY-AREA

        STOP RUN
```

compiler messages:

```
Circles.cbl:28: error: PROCEDURE DIVISION header missing
Circles.cbl:28: error: syntax error, unexpected level-number
Circles.cbl:29: error: unknown statement '05'
Circles.cbl:30: error: unknown statement '05'
Circles.cbl:34: error: syntax error, unexpected PROCEDURE
Circles.cbl: in paragraph '0100-PROCESS-RECORDS':
Circles.cbl:40: error: 'WS-RADIUS' is not defined
Circles.cbl:41: error: 'WS-CIRCUMFRENCE' is not defined
Circles.cbl:41: error: 'WS-PI' is not defined
Circles.cbl:41: error: 'WS-RADIUS' is not defined
Circles.cbl:42: error: 'WS-CIRCUMFRENCE' is not defined
Circles.cbl:42: error: 'WS-DISPLAY-CIRCUMFRENCE' is not defined
Circles.cbl:43: error: 'WS-DISPLAY-CIRCUM' is not defined
Circles.cbl:44: error: 'WS-RADIUS' is not defined
Circles.cbl:44: error: 'WS-PI' is not defined
Circles.cbl:44: error: 'WS-RADIUS' is not defined
Circles.cbl:44: error: 'WS-RADIUS' is not defined
Circles.cbl:45: error: 'WS-AREA' is not defined
Circles.cbl:45: error: 'WS-DISPLAY-AREA' is not defined
Circles.cbl:46: error: 'WS-DISPLAY-AREA' is not defined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After putting your program into an online compiler (code+results [here](http://tpcg.io/1f6HmR)) two issues were seen:

- typo: `WS-CIRCUMFRENCE` -> `WS-CIRCUMFENCE`
- missing separator period at the end

As you seem to not use free format but the column based one I've removed that option (`-free` from this project, fixed the issues specified above and added the minimal indentation, result: [works like a charm](http://tpcg.io/NPLNDg).

I thought about possible issues but the only one I could think of was an additional specification of `DECIMAL-POINT IS COMMA` - but that raises `error: invalid level number '14159'`, or bad indentation (this would likely be seen); you *may* want to recheck that you don't do the indentation by TABs (their actual size may differ between what you editor shows and what the compiler uses [most compilers use a size of 8 spaces by default).

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the above suggestions I'd also add change

```
COMPUTE WS-RADIUS = WS-PI * WS-RADIUS * WS-RADIUS.
```

to

```
COMPUTE WS-AREA = WS-PI * WS-RADIUS * WS-RADIUS.
```

or you'll always print out 0 for area